# In Unix, user having the highest UID?

Tags: unix

Can some one please tell me how can I find the following.

List from /etc/passwd the UID and the user having the highest UID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $3,$1}' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

Comment: you can also substitute `awk` with `cut` :  `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f3 | sort -n | tail -n 1`

Comment: @nsr: That won't print the user name though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers and comments, they was very helpful

Comment: @sepp2k: oops, missed that parts.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of reading `/etc/passwd`, it would be better to get the output from

```
getent passwd
```

As you could be using another source of UIDs via nsswitch, such as LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/passwd` contains user information separated by colons. The user id is in the third column.

The `sort` command line tool can be used to sort the lines of a file. It has options, to choose which separator the columns are separated by, which column to sort by and whether to sort numerically or alphabetically.

So you can use `sort` to sort `/etc/passwd` by user id and then use `tail` to get the last line from that, which will contain the user with highest id.

Answer (score 0):

```
getent passwd | awk -F : '$3>h{h=$3;u=$1}END{print h " " u}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The getent output needs to be sorted for the awk command.
In addition, I found that nfsnobody (on Linux) can be ignored and the next highest UID is what is often needed.  So this worked well:

```sh
getent passwd |sort -t: -k3 -n |awk -F: '$3>h{ph=h;pu=u;h=$3;u=$1}END{print h,u"\n"ph,pu}'
```

`65534 nfsnobody 1002 user2`